# How to write a hyperlink inside js file

Tags: javascript

I have a code generated by the marzipano tool. I'd like to place a link together with a description inside the `js` file *(see attached marked green)*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that Java _is not_ JavaScript. Besides that, what's the problem? What did you try so far?

Comment: I have a file generated by "marzipanotool", the file is data.js. In that file I have a title for my image and description. I will write a description for that image and i need to place a hyperlink inside poininting to another website. Hope it's clear explained

Comment: If there is nothing else in that file, only this `var APP_DATA = {};`, you can manually remove the `var APP_DATA =` prefix and the trailing `;`, and parse the rest as JSON. Popular libraries like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) can help in the process. Change what you need, and serialize back the result with the prefix+trailer.

Comment: Or, an extremely low-budget approach would be writing there an absolutely unique placeholder (`Description with the hyperlink` may already do the job), [read the file into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file), replace the unique stuff and write the result back. No external libraries or parsing involved.

Comment: I just need the word "hyperlink" be an link pointing to external webpage, like html tag: <a href="https://www.webpage.com/">hyperlink</a> How to do that inside js file

Comment: In that case why don't you just replace that word with escaped html?

Comment: how? could write it in here

Comment: Add `"link" : "www.website.com"` to your JS file, and then use it in your HTML to produce `<a href="www.website.com">hyperlink</a>`

Comment: i figured out :) thanks